# Comparing two lists in excel and extracting values missing from 2nd list - cannot be duplicated (also over two sheets)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Im working on a project report for work and I'm trying to find a way to compare two lists of project codes i.e "123456" and see whether the 2nd list is missing any new values that would've been entered into the first list. The lists are thousands of records long and so far people have been doing it manually (it hurts me knowing this) so I'm trying to make it automatic.

What I have tried is using an Array with a Index(Match(CountIF))) formula but I just cant seem to get it working.

[image: Example]

My problem is that when I get the array to fill with what i want I then can't get it to not duplicate values (I need it to check the masterlist so it doesnt output something more than once into the output list).

I've also tried to give it a go with other formulas - but the lists can be thousands of records long so I cant do a cell for cell match as the list would be huge (that or my excel knowledge isnt good enough to know the easy solution).

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

- Array might not be the best solution
- I've checked quite a few other solutions but they don't quite deal with my issue and I don't have the skill to adapt them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using VBA and arrays which is quicker than doing via the sheet. It checks each item in H to see it is present in J (and not the other way round). I assume that's what you want.

```
Sub x()

Dim v1, v2, v3(), i As Long, j As Long

v1 = Range("H2", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
v2 = Range("J2", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

ReDim v3(1 To UBound(v1, 1))

For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
    If IsError(Application.Match(v1(i, 1), v2, 0)) Then
        j = j + 1
        v3(j) = v1(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

Range("K2").Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(v3)

End Sub
```

Using an input box

```
Sub x()

Dim v1, v2, v3(), i As Long, j As Long

v1 = Application.InputBox("First list", Type:=8)
v2 = Application.InputBox("Second list", Type:=8)

ReDim v3(1 To UBound(v1, 1))

For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
    If IsError(Application.Match(v1(i, 1), v2, 0)) Then
        j = j + 1
        v3(j) = v1(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
Range("K2").Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(v3)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SJR - I will try to give this a go. I am not confident with VBA but have basic experience with it in the past. I will update you on how it goes

Comment: Hi SJR - this works nicely. It prints out the correct list as is an easily executed macro. How would i get the vba code to refer to a different sheet, cant I make it show a pop-up where I can highlight each range. Or could I use the named range tool to mark out the ranges I need it to compare? Edit: looking into this now myself

Comment: Yes, I've added alternative code below in which you select the two ranges. And could be extended for the ouput cell too.

Comment: I ended up using v1 = Application.InputBox("Select All project list range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8). Found it in another thread - the extra text is just the name of the window. Thanks for all your help! My next step is to then add further distinguishing criteria during the list comparison. I will need to use a Vlookup to then only select rows that have an 'A' in the cell 5 columns to the right. Would I be correct in assuming an addition of an AND statement in the If clause with a vlookup operation would work?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you include the other columns when you select the appropriate range.

Comment: yeah - for the table array for the Vlookup variable - Thanks for your help SJR its been really great

Answer (score 2):

A formula solution.
Note that I turned the first two ranges into `Tables` and changed the names.  The formula is using structured references.  This enables the formula to auto update if you add rows in the future.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ProjList1[#Data],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNA(MATCH(ProjList1[#Data],ProjList2[#Data],0))*ROW(ProjList1[#Data]),ROWS($1:1))-ROW(ProjList1[#Headers])),"")
```

How does it work?   Briefly:

- `MATCH` generates an array of `#NA!` errors or a number.
- `ISNA` turns that into an array of `TRUE/FALSE` where `TRUE` indicates an entry in table 1 that is NOT in table 2
- Multiplying that array by the array of project list rows returns an array of error message vs row number
- `AGGREGATE` small function ignores the error returns to give an ascending list of row numbers
- `INDEX` then returns the appropriate entry from Table 1
- `ROW(ProjList1[#Headers])` is a correction so that the table may be located anyplace on the worksheet, and still return the correct row.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the detailed answer. In terms of implementing this into action. Would there be any bits of the formula I would have to edit/adjust for the parameters I need. I.e you renamed the headers to make it easier (does this need to have no spaces?).

Also you specified you turned the two ranges into Tables. Can you define what you mean by this as I am not familiar with that terminology - in the essence of how you "turn" the ranges into a Table.

I am familiar with named ranges - but not with converting ranges into Tables - sorry about this.

Comment: @JacobCrux For a discussion of Excel tables and how to use them, see Debra Dagleish's discussion of [Creating an Excel Table](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to set this up so it will autoupdate in future, but as a stopgap:

Countif column next to list 1 that checks whether they appear in list 2...
... Feeding into a pivot that only shows those where the countif value is 0, in the "row" field to remove duplication?